# Select From -> Select To jquery

Tags: jquery, select

Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I have a div with two select elements (note that they're dynamically created and don't have ids). Both of them contain same option elements (Skill Levels that go from 1 to 5). When a user selects something from the SelectFrom dropbox I the second option (Select To) to only contain the options with value bigger than the selected in the Select From.

If the user selects the default element in the Select From dropbox (with no value) I want to repopulate the Select to with the 5 elements.

I figured out that i'm gonna have a hidden select element with all 5 options and I'm gonna clone those and repopulate the Select to dropbox.

What is the way to go forward. The tricky part is that I don't have Ids so I'm working with parent() and siblings(). Thanks for your time

Let's assume this is the HTML:

```
<div>
<select class="skillsFrom">
<option value="">Please select a value</option>
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">a</option>
<option value="3">a</option>
<option value="4">a</option>
<option value="5">a</option>
</select>
<select class="skillsTo">
<option value="">Please select a value</option>
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">a</option>
<option value="3">a</option>
<option value="4">a</option>
<option value="5">a</option>
</select>
</div>
```

here's JS:
//btw helperSelect is a select with the same options as the other two it is just hidden.

```
('.skillsFrom').bind('change', function(){

            var $optionsSkillLevel = $('#helperSelect option').clone();

            var selectedValue = $(this).val();

            $(this).parent().siblings('.skillsTo').html($optionsSkillLevel);

            if(selectedValue != ''){

            }

        });
```

And I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I want to iterate over all elements in Select To and remove those that are lower than the selected value from Select From

Comment: what is the exact HTML structure of your DIV including the two selects?

Comment: it is a HUGE .jsp so I cannot paste the html here. I will do a mock

Comment: HUGE .jsp?? I only want to see the DIV and the two selects in it ... so that we can determine their "positions" in the DOM relative to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every change of the first select you need to hide/show certain options of the second one.

```
$('.skillsFrom').change(function() {
    var theValue = $(this).val();
    if($(this).val()==="") {
        // show all values of .skillsTo if .skillsFrom select is set to ""
        $(this).parent().find('.skillsTo option').show();
    } else {
        theValue = parseInt(theValue, 10);
        $(this).parent().find('.skillsTo option').each(function() {
           if(parseInt($(this).val(), 10) <= theValue) {
               // hide if value <= selected value from .selectFrom
               $(this).hide();
           } else {
               // show if value > selected value from .selectFrom
               $(this).show();
           }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: THe prob is that I have X number of such container divs.. There will by X number of select elements with the class of .skillsFrom and .skillsTo. This will not work because you're not going up and down the DOM to select the element with the class of .skillsTo in that particular div :/

Comment: This only works for the first time the event fires on skillsFrom. Then it never updates the corresponding skillsTo select element any longer :/

Comment: One more thing.. your solution only works, partially (read the comment above) in mozilla :/

Comment: I also tested in Chrome ... but granted, it doesn't work in IE, don't know why though

Comment: does it only work the first time you call the change event for you aswell?

Comment: No, for Firefox and Chrome it works "indefinitely": http://jsbin.com/arewod/1/edit

Comment: even in the jsbin I posted with my latest comment?

Comment: in jsbin it works.. in my .jsp it doesnt.. I marked your answer as correct. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
$('.skillsFrom').change(function() {
  var val = this.value;
  if(val == '') {
    // your reload logic here
  }
  else {
    $('.skillsTo option').hide().filter(function() {
        return this.value != '' && parseInt(this.value, 10) > parseInt(val, 10);
    }).show();
  }
});
```